# Android app using HttpURLConnection crashes at connect()

Tags: java, android, http, url

I have a following piece of code, basically copy-pasted from examples as I am new to Java and Android (not to programming):

```
      URL vurl = new URL(voteurl); //vuteurl is a string containing a proper URL
      HttpURLConnection hc;
      hc=null;
      hc = (HttpURLConnection)vurl.openConnection();
      hc.setRequestMethod("GET");
      hc.setDoOutput(true);
      hc.setReadTimeout(10000);
      hc.connect();
```

On the line "hc.connect();" the application crashes and Android informs me that it had been stopped.
Adding android.permission.INTERNET to the permisions used by the app did not help.

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace of the crash?

Comment: Is the code shown surrounded in a try/catch block?

Comment: Look into logcat output there must be more info about the exception in there

Comment: Are you performing this network operation on the main thread? If so, you may be experiencing a NetworkOnMainThreadException. As others have said, please post the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: But, I've looked through the stuff in LogCat - it's the NetworkOnMainThreadException. So is it a crime to perform network operations in the main thread on Android?

Comment: Anyway, everything works now as I've done all that in a separate thread.

Comment: Android won't let you do network operations on the main thread in newer versions because there is a risk that the network operation will be too slow and lock up your device because the main thread is waiting for completion before performing another task.

Comment: You can answer yourself, so people will know that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

OK, turns out Android doesn't like network operations in the main thread.
Doing a request in a separate thread does the trick. Thanks guys for Your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
URL vurl = null;
    try {
        vurl = new URL(voteurl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } //vuteurl is a string containing a proper URL
    HttpURLConnection hc;
    hc=null;
    try {
        hc = (HttpURLConnection)vurl.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        hc.setRequestMethod("GET");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    hc.setDoOutput(true);
    hc.setReadTimeout(10000);
    try {
        hc.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```